# Sum large pandas dataframe based on smaller date ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe that has hourly data associated with it.  I then want to parse that into "monthly" data that sums the hourly data.  However, the months aren't necessarily calendar months, they typically start in the middle of one month and end in the middle of the next month.

I could build a list of the "months" that each of these date ranges fall into and loop through it, but I would think there is a much better way to do this via pandas.

Here's my current code, the last line throws an error and is the crux of the question:

```
dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range('1/1/2015 00:00','3/31/2015 23:45',freq='1H'))
nums = np.random.randint(0,100,dates.count())
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'num':nums})

month = pd.DataFrame({'start':['1/4/2015 00:00','1/24/2015 00:00'], 'end':['1/23/2015 23:00','2/23/2015 23:00']})
month['start'] = pd.to_datetime(month['start'])
month['end'] = pd.to_datetime(month['end'])

month['num'] = df['num'][(df['date'] >= month['start']) & (df['date'] <= month['end'])].sum()
```

I would want an output similar to:

```
       start                 end    num
0 2015-01-04 2015-01-23 23:00:00 33,251
1 2015-01-24 2015-02-23 23:00:00 39,652
```

but of course, I'm not getting that.

Comment: Try looking at pd.tseries.offsets.Month and see if there is a start date and resample by that. If no start date add a timedelta of the day of the month that you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***`pd.merge_asof` only available with pandas 0.19***
combination of [`pd.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof) + [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) + [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

```
pd.merge_asof(df, month, left_on='date', right_on='start') \
    .query('date <= end').groupby(['start', 'end']).num.sum().reset_index()
```

[image]

---

***explanation***
*`pd.merge_asof`*
From docs

> For each row in the left DataFrame, we select the last row in the right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is less than or equal to the left’s key. Both DataFrames must be sorted by the key.

But this only takes into account the `start` date.

*`query`*
I take care of `end` date with `query` since I now conveniently have `end` in my dataframe after `pd.merge_asof`

*`groupby`*
I trust this part is obvious`

Comment: I'm getting: `'module' object has no attribute 'merge_asof'`

Comment: Its a pandas 0.19 feature.

Comment: If you can't upgrade, we'll have to find another solution

Comment: As always @piRSquared - you are the king of one-liners.  Thank you much!

Comment: @pshep123 where's that hat?

Comment: This seems like too much of a brute force answer. You should be able to shift the dates a constant amount and convert each date to a pandas `Period` and then group on this period and sum. All without a lookup table for start and end date.

Comment: @TedPetrou I'd disagree.  This generalizes very well to arbitrary periods.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can convert to a period and add a number of days

```
# create data
dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range('1/1/2015 00:00','3/31/2015 23:45',freq='1H'))
nums = np.random.randint(0,100,dates.count())
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'num':nums})

# offset days and then create period
df['periods'] = (df.date + pd.tseries.offsets.Day(23)).dt.to_period('M')]

# group and sum
df.groupby('periods')['num'].sum()
```

Output

```
periods
2015-01    10051
2015-02    34229
2015-03    37311
2015-04    26655
```

You can then shift the dates back and make new columns