# Pandas: Add amount in Dataframe based on date ranges and IDs

Tags: python, pandas

I asked a question a while back ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314324/sum-large-pandas-dataframe-based-on-smaller-date-ranges)) about how to find the sum of a column in a dataframe by comparing dates in another dataframe.  However, I now want to do something similar but include an ID that may have an exact matching date with another ID.

Here is my code:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({
        'end':pd.to_datetime(['1/15/2016','1/15/2016','3/15/2016','5/15/2016','5/15/2016','7/15/2016']),
        'ID':[1,2,1,2,1,1]
    })

df_a['start'] = df_a.groupby('ID')['end'].shift().fillna(0)
df_a = df_a[['start','end','ID']]

df_b = pd.DataFrame({
        'date':pd.to_datetime(['1/1/2016','1/1/2016','2/1/2016','2/1/2016','3/1/2016','3/1/2016','6/1/2016','6/1/2016','7/1/2016','7/1/2016','8/1/2016']),
        'ID':       [1, 2, 1,  2,  1,   2,   2,    1,    1,     2,     2],
        'amount':   [1, 2, 10, 20, 100, 200, 2000, 1000, 10000, 20000, 200000]
    })
```

And my desired output:

```
         start        end   ID   amount
0   1970-01-01 2016-01-15    1        1
1   1970-01-01 2016-01-15    2        2
2   2016-01-15 2016-03-15    1      110
3   2016-01-15 2016-05-15    2      220
4   2016-03-15 2016-05-15    1        0
5   2016-05-15 2016-07-15    1    11000
```

I've tried `merge()`, `merge_asof()`, `combine_first()`, `groupby()` and gotten close, but not all the way.

Here is a non-pandas version that works, but for a large data set, I imagine this would be quite slow:

```
amount = []
for s, e, i in zip(df_a['start'], df_a['end'], df_a['ID']):
    amount.append(df_b['amount'][(s < df_b['date']) & (df_b['date'] <= e) & (df_b['ID'] == i)].sum())

df_a['amount'] = pd.Series(amount)
```

Would love some help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is pretty good.  I like this because using `reindex` with `fill_value` preserves the `int` `dtype`

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df_a.values.T, names=df_a.columns)

kws = dict(
    left_on='date', right_on='start',
    allow_exact_matches=True, by='ID')
mrg = pd.merge_asof(df_b, df_a, **kws).query('date <= end')
grp = mrg.groupby(['start', 'end', 'ID']).amount.sum()
grp.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()

       start        end  ID  amount
0 1970-01-01 2016-01-15   1       1
1 1970-01-01 2016-01-15   2       2
2 2016-01-15 2016-03-15   1     110
3 2016-01-15 2016-05-15   2     220
4 2016-03-15 2016-05-15   1       0
5 2016-05-15 2016-07-15   1   11000
```

Comment: I'm gonna mark this as the correct answer, because it works, but *wow*.  That's some higher-level pandas that I'll need some time to digest.  Great learning experience, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I answered my own question based on the link I shared in my original question (thanks @piRSquared), but had to add a little code.  I'm guessing this isn't the most efficient method and would be interested in getting other thoughts.

```
# Merge DataFrames, find date ranges, and add amounts    
df_c = pd.merge_asof(df_b, df_a, left_on = 'date', right_on = 'start', by = 'ID') \ 
         .query('date <= end').groupby(['end','ID'])['amount'].sum().reset_index()

# But that leaves out ranges for which there is no data
# so need to merge back in the original dates and fill NaNs with 0    
df_c = df_a.merge(df_c, how = 'outer').fillna(0)

       start        end   ID   amount
0 1970-01-01 2016-01-15    1      1.0
1 1970-01-01 2016-01-15    2      2.0
2 2016-01-15 2016-03-15    1    110.0
3 2016-01-15 2016-05-15    2    220.0
4 2016-03-15 2016-05-15    1      0.0
5 2016-05-15 2016-07-15    1  11000.0
```

Comment: That looks pretty good.  I did it a little bit differently based on preference  but I think using merge at the end to get that zero in row 4, is smart.